# Generate rows for each number in integer

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle18c

I have a ROADS table:

```
with cte as (
select      1 as road_id,      2 as num_vertices    from dual
union all
select      2 as road_id,   null as num_vertices    from dual
union all
select      3 as road_id,   1000 as num_vertices    from dual
)
select
    *
from
    cte

   ROAD_ID NUM_VERTICES
---------- ------------
         1            2
         2         null
         3         1000
```

---

For each road, I want to generate rows for each vertex:

```
   ROAD_ID       VERTEX
---------- ------------
         1            1
         1            2
         3            1
         3            2
         3          ...
         3         1000
```

---

Question:

Is there a way to generate rows in a SELECT query for each NUM_VERTICES integer?

Comment: Related: [Query for ST_Geometry line vertices via a recursive SQL WITH clause?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/412833/query-for-st-geometry-line-vertices-via-a-recursive-sql-with-clause/413621#413621)

Answer (score 2):

One method is a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select      1 as road_id,      2 as num_vertices    from dual
      union all
      select      2 as road_id,   null as num_vertices    from dual
      union all
      select      3 as road_id,   1000 as num_vertices    from dual
     ),
     rcte (road_id, vertex, num_vertices) as (
      select road_id, 1 as vertex, num_vertices
      from cte
      where num_vertices > 0
      union all
      select road_id, vertex + 1, num_vertices
      from rcte
      where vertex < num_vertices
     )
select road_id, vertex
from rcte;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5381a7179e413599931642a91f76b420) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @User1973 . . . I prefer recursive CTEs because they are part of standard SQL.  On the other hand, `connect` has been in Oracle for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

CONNECT BY and a CROSS JOIN seem to do the trick too:

```
select level as vertex from dual connect by level <= (select max(cte.num_vertices) from cte )
```

The full query:

```
with cte as (
select      1 as road_id,      2 as num_vertices    from dual
union all
select      2 as road_id,   null as num_vertices    from dual
union all
select      3 as road_id,   1000 as num_vertices    from dual
),
numbers as (select level as vertex from dual connect by level <= (select max(cte.num_vertices) from cte ))
select
    *
from
    cte
cross join
     numbers
where    
    vertex <= num_vertices
order by
    road_id,
    vertex
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a180e547688d09335afee2b03c543755)